# AppSettings and ApplicationSettings in the same config file

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I created an application that uses applicationSettings in the config file.  This app uses an older library that reads data from appSettings.  I can't seem to use both of these sections in the same config file.  AppSettings always returns null when ApplicationSettings is configured.  Am I missing something?  I searched all over for others with the same problem with no success.  --Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know why I had the problem. Maybe it was something wrong with my config file. Either way it seems to work now.